# OmniFaces 3.0 and MyFaces 2.2.12 throws java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory

Tags: jsf, myfaces, omnifaces

During myfaces initialization on jboss-fuse 6.3.0283, InvocationTargetException has been thrown in karaf. Does that mean omnifaces will not properly work with myfaces 2.2.12 bundle or are there some dependent classes which are not loaded by the container?

By the way, we are using primefaces 6.1 and pax-cdi-web-weld for cdi. The features and bundles which installed and active are:

```
<feature version="1.0.0.RC1-redhat-001">pax-cdi-web-weld</feature>

<bundle>mvn:commons-digester/commons-digester/1.8.1</bundle>
<bundle>mvn:org.apache.myfaces.core/myfaces-bundle/2.2.12</bundle>
<bundle>mvn:org.primefaces/primefaces/6.1</bundle>
<bundle>wrap:mvn:org.primefaces.extensions/primefaces-extensions/6.1.1</bundle>
```

Felix Plugin:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>bundle-manifest</id>
        <phase>process-classes</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>manifest</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
<extensions>true</extensions>
<configuration>
    <instructions>
        <_wab>src/main/webapp</_wab>
        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${bundle.symbolicName}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
        <Import-Package>
            com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation;version="[2.6,3)",
            com.fasterxml.jackson.core;version="[2.6,3)",
            com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module;version="[2.6,3)",
            com.fasterxml.jackson.databind;version="[2.6,3)",
            com.google.gson;version="[2.2,3)",
            javax.annotation;version="[1.2,2)",
            javax.crypto,
            javax.crypto.spec,
            javax.el;version="[2.2,3)",
            javax.enterprise.context;version="[1.1,2)",
            javax.enterprise.context.spi;version="[1.1,2)",
            javax.enterprise.event;version="[1.1,2)",
            javax.enterprise.inject.spi;version="[1.1,2)",
            javax.faces.application;version="[2.2,3)",
            javax.faces.bean;version="[2.2,3)",
            javax.faces.component.behavior;version="[2.2,3)",
            javax.faces.component.html;version="[2.2,3)",
            javax.faces.component.visit;version="[2.2,3)",
            javax.faces.component;version="[2.2,3)",
            javax.faces.context;version="[2.2,3)",
            javax.faces.convert;version="[2.2,3)",
            javax.faces.el;version="[2.2,3)",
            javax.faces.event;version="[2.2,3)",
            javax.faces.lifecycle;version="[2.2,3)",
            javax.faces.model;version="[2.2,3)",
            javax.faces.render;version="[2.2,3)",
            javax.faces.validator;version="[2.2,3)",
            javax.faces.view.facelets;version="[2.2,3)",
            javax.faces.view;version="[2.2,3)",
            javax.faces.webapp;version="[2.2,3)",
            javax.faces;version="[2.2,3)",
            javax.inject,
            javax.naming,
            javax.servlet.http;version="[3.1,4)",
            javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core;version=1.2,
            javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt;version=1.2,
            javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv;version=1.2,
            javax.servlet.jsp;version="[2.2.0,3.0.0)",
            javax.servlet;version="[3.1,4)",
            javax.websocket,
            javax.websocket.server,
            javax.xml.parsers,
            org.apache.commons.lang3,
            org.apache.commons.logging,
            org.apache.taglibs.standard.resources;version=1.1.2,
            org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core;version=1.1.2,
            org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core;version=1.1.2,
            org.apache.taglibs.standard.tei;version=1.1.2,
            org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv;version=1.1.2,
            org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin;version="[2.3,3)",
            org.jboss.weld.el;version="[2.3,3)",
            org.jboss.weld.manager;version="[2.3,3)",
            org.jboss.weld.servlet;version="[2.3,3)",
            org.jboss.weld.util;version="[2.3,3)",
            org.ops4j.pax.cdi.api;version="[1.0,2)",
            org.osgi.framework;version="[1.7,2)",
            org.osgi.service.blueprint.container;version="[1.0,2)",
            org.osgi.service.log;version="[1.3,2)",
            org.osgi.util.tracker;version="[1.5,2)",
            org.primefaces.context;version="[6.1,7)",
            org.primefaces.event;version="[6.1,7)",
            org.slf4j;version="[1.7,2)",
            org.w3c.dom,
            org.xml.sax,
            org.xml.sax.ext,
            org.xml.sax.helpers
        </Import-Package>
        <Export-Package>!*</Export-Package>
        <Bundle-Classpath>
            WEB-INF/classes,
            WEB-INF/lib/all-themes-1.0.10.jar,
            WEB-INF/lib/commons-lang3-3.7.jar,
            WEB-INF/lib/aspectjrt-1.8.9.jar,
            WEB-INF/lib/resources-codemirror-6.1.1.jar,
            WEB-INF/lib/omnifaces-3.0.jar
        </Bundle-Classpath>
        <Web-ContextPath>${web.context.path}</Web-ContextPath>
        <Require-Bundle>
            org.primefaces;visibility:=reexport,
            org.apache.myfaces.core.bundle;visibility:=reexport,
            wrap_mvn_org.primefaces.extensions_primefaces-extensions_6.1.1;visibility:=reexport
        </Require-Bundle>
        <Require-Capability>
            osgi.extender; filter:="(osgi.extender=pax.cdi)",org.ops4j.pax.cdi.extension; filter:="(extension=pax-cdi-extension)"
        </Require-Capability>
        <_removeheaders>
            Include-Resource,
            Private-Package,
            Embed-Dependency,
            Embed-Transitive
        </_removeheaders>
    </instructions>
    <supportedProjectTypes>
        <supportedProjectType>jar</supportedProjectType>
        <supportedProjectType>bundle</supportedProjectType>
        <supportedProjectType>war</supportedProjectType>
    </supportedProjectTypes>
</configuration>
```

Exception:

```
2018-01-07 12:54:31,283 | ERROR | FelixStartLevel  | AbstractFacesInitializer         | 351 - org.apache.myfaces.core.bundle - 2.2.12 | An error occured while initializing MyFaces: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
javax.faces.FacesException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.newFactoryInstance(FactoryFinder.java:544)[351:org.apache.myfaces.core.bundle:2.2.12]
        at javax.faces.FactoryFinder._getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:361)[351:org.apache.myfaces.core.bundle:2.2.12]
        at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:225)[351:org.apache.myfaces.core.bundle:2.2.12]
        at org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator.configureApplication(FacesConfigurator.java:695)
        at org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator.configure(FacesConfigurator.java:595)
        at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.buildConfiguration(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:416)[351:org.apache.myfaces.core.bundle:2.2.12]
        at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.Jsp21FacesInitializer.initContainerIntegration(Jsp21FacesInitializer.java:73)[351:org.apache.myfaces.core.bundle:2.2.12]
        at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.initFaces(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:172)[351:org.apache.myfaces.core.bundle:2.2.12]
        at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.contextInitialized(StartupServletContextListener.java:121)[351:org.apache.myfaces.core.bundle:2.2.12]
        at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext$3.call(HttpServiceContext.java:354)[115:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:4.3.1]
        at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext$3.call(HttpServiceContext.java:350)[115:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:4.3.1]
        at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.core.ContextClassLoaderUtils.doWithClassLoader(ContextClassLoaderUtils.java:60)[115:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:4.3.1]
        at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext.callContextInitialized(HttpServiceContext.java:349)[115:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:4.3.1]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:791)[91:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.2.21.v20170120]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:294)[92:org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:9.2.21.v20170120]
        at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext.startContext(HttpServiceContext.java:601)[115:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:4.3.1]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)[91:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.2.21.v20170120]
        at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext.doStart(HttpServiceContext.java:260)[115:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:4.3.1]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)[94:org.eclipse.jetty.util:9.2.21.v20170120]
        at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.JettyServerImpl$1.start(JettyServerImpl.java:284)[115:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:4.3.1]
        at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.HttpServiceStarted.end(HttpServiceStarted.java:1096)
        at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.HttpServiceProxy.end(HttpServiceProxy.java:417)
        at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.RegisterWebAppVisitorWC.end(RegisterWebAppVisitorWC.java:380)
        at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.model.WebApp.accept(WebApp.java:692)
        at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher$WebAppDependencyListener.register(WebAppPublisher.java:237)
        at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher$WebAppDependencyListener.addingService(WebAppPublisher.java:182)
        at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher$WebAppDependencyListener.addingService(WebAppPublisher.java:135)
        at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:932)[karaf.jar:2.4.0.redhat-630283]
        at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:1)[karaf.jar:2.4.0.redhat-630283]
        at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)[152:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.4]
        at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.track(AbstractTracked.java:229)[152:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.4]
        at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.serviceChanged(ServiceTracker.java:894)[karaf.jar:2.4.0.redhat-630283]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.invokeServiceListenerCallback(EventDispatcher.java:943)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireEventImmediately(EventDispatcher.java:794)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireServiceEvent(EventDispatcher.java:544)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireServiceEvent(Felix.java:4445)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.registerService(Felix.java:3431)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:346)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:353)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
        at org.ops4j.pax.cdi.web.AbstractWebAppDependencyManager.register(AbstractWebAppDependencyManager.java:57)
        at org.ops4j.pax.cdi.web.AbstractWebAppDependencyManager.postCreate(AbstractWebAppDependencyManager.java:84)
        at org.ops4j.pax.cdi.extender.impl.CdiExtender.doCreateLazyContainer(CdiExtender.java:202)
        at org.ops4j.pax.cdi.extender.impl.CdiExtender.handleWebBundles(CdiExtender.java:226)
        at org.ops4j.pax.cdi.extender.impl.CdiExtender.setWebAdapter(CdiExtender.java:219)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.8.0_151]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)[:1.8.0_151]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.8.0_151]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)[:1.8.0_151]
        at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod.invokeMethod(BaseMethod.java:231)[152:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.4]
        at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod.access$500(BaseMethod.java:39)[152:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.4]
        at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod$Resolved.invoke(BaseMethod.java:624)[152:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.4]
        at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod.invoke(BaseMethod.java:508)[152:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.4]
        at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BindMethod.invoke(BindMethod.java:37)[152:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.4]
        at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.DependencyManager.doInvokeBindMethod(DependencyManager.java:1608)[152:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.4]
        at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.DependencyManager.invokeBindMethod(DependencyManager.java:1593)[152:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.4]
        at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.invokeBindMethod(SingleComponentManager.java:382)[152:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.4]
        at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.DependencyManager$SingleDynamicCustomizer.addedService(DependencyManager.java:708)[152:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.4]
        at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.DependencyManager$SingleDynamicCustomizer.addedService(DependencyManager.java:674)[152:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.4]
        at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdded(ServiceTracker.java:1480)[152:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.4]
        at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdded(ServiceTracker.java:1401)[152:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.4]
        at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ServiceTracker$AbstractTracked.trackAdding(ServiceTracker.java:1210)[152:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.4]
        at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ServiceTracker$AbstractTracked.track(ServiceTracker.java:1148)[152:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.4]
        at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ServiceTracker$Tracked.serviceChanged(ServiceTracker.java:1432)[152:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.4]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.invokeServiceListenerCallback(EventDispatcher.java:943)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireEventImmediately(EventDispatcher.java:794)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireServiceEvent(EventDispatcher.java:544)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireServiceEvent(Felix.java:4445)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.registerService(Felix.java:3431)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:346)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager$3.register(AbstractComponentManager.java:1003)[152:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.4]
        at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager$3.register(AbstractComponentManager.java:992)[152:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.4]
        at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.RegistrationManager.changeRegistration(RegistrationManager.java:134)[152:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.4]
        at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.registerService(AbstractComponentManager.java:1044)[152:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.4]
        at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.activateInternal(AbstractComponentManager.java:841)[152:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.4]
        at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.enable(AbstractComponentManager.java:419)[152:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.4]
        at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.config.ConfigurableComponentHolder.enableComponents(ConfigurableComponentHolder.java:376)[152:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.4]
        at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.BundleComponentActivator.initialize(BundleComponentActivator.java:172)[152:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.4]
        at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.BundleComponentActivator.<init>(BundleComponentActivator.java:120)[152:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.4]
        at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.Activator.loadComponents(Activator.java:258)[152:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.4]
        at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.Activator.access$000(Activator.java:45)[152:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.4]
        at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.Activator$ScrExtension.start(Activator.java:185)[152:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.4]
        at org.apache.felix.utils.extender.AbstractExtender.createExtension(AbstractExtender.java:259)[152:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.4]
        at org.apache.felix.utils.extender.AbstractExtender.modifiedBundle(AbstractExtender.java:232)[152:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.4]
        at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleTracker.java:479)[152:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.4]
        at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleTracker.java:414)[152:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.4]
        at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.track(AbstractTracked.java:232)[152:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.4]
        at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.bundleChanged(BundleTracker.java:443)[152:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.4]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.invokeBundleListenerCallback(EventDispatcher.java:869)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireEventImmediately(EventDispatcher.java:790)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireBundleEvent(EventDispatcher.java:515)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireBundleEvent(Felix.java:4429)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2100)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1299)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:304)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)[:1.8.0_151]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)[:1.8.0_151]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)[:1.8.0_151]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)[:1.8.0_151]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)[:1.8.0_151]
        at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.newFactoryInstance(FactoryFinder.java:531)[351:org.apache.myfaces.core.bundle:2.2.12]
        ... 94 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory.<init>(Ljavax/faces/application/ApplicationFactory;)V`


**Pax Extender Exception:**

`2018-01-07 12:54:32,289 | ERROR | FelixStartLevel  | WebAppPublisher                  | 276 - org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war - 4.3.1 | Error deploying web application
java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
        at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.validateConstructorArguments(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:58)[:1.8.0_151]
        at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.<init>(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:51)[:1.8.0_151]
        at sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl.make(ParameterizedTypeImpl.java:92)[:1.8.0_151]
        at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeParameterizedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:105)[:1.8.0_151]
        at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:140)[:1.8.0_151]
        at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)[:1.8.0_151]
        at sun.reflect.generics.repository.MethodRepository.getReturnType(MethodRepository.java:68)[:1.8.0_151]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.getGenericReturnType(Method.java:255)[:1.8.0_151]
        at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedMethod.<init>(BackedAnnotatedMethod.java:38)[348:org.jboss.weld.osgi-bundle:2.3.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedMethod.of(BackedAnnotatedMethod.java:32)[348:org.jboss.weld.osgi-bundle:2.3.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$BackedAnnotatedMethods.computeValue(BackedAnnotatedType.java:195)[348:org.jboss.weld.osgi-bundle:2.3.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$BackedAnnotatedMethods.computeValue(BackedAnnotatedType.java:188)[348:org.jboss.weld.osgi-bundle:2.3.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.weld.util.LazyValueHolder.get(LazyValueHolder.java:35)[348:org.jboss.weld.osgi-bundle:2.3.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$EagerlyInitializedLazyValueHolder.<init>(BackedAnnotatedType.java:156)[348:org.jboss.weld.osgi-bundle:2.3.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$BackedAnnotatedMethods.<init>(BackedAnnotatedType.java:188)[348:org.jboss.weld.osgi-bundle:2.3.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$BackedAnnotatedMethods.<init>(BackedAnnotatedType.java:188)[348:org.jboss.weld.osgi-bundle:2.3.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType.<init>(BackedAnnotatedType.java:63)[348:org.jboss.weld.osgi-bundle:2.3.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType.of(BackedAnnotatedType.java:44)[348:org.jboss.weld.osgi-bundle:2.3.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformClassToBackedAnnotatedType.load(ClassTransformer.java:83)[348:org.jboss.weld.osgi-bundle:2.3.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformClassToBackedAnnotatedType.load(ClassTransformer.java:80)[348:org.jboss.weld.osgi-bundle:2.3.2.Final]
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3527)[129:com.google.guava:18.0.0.redhat-1]
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2319)[129:com.google.guava:18.0.0.redhat-1]
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2282)[129:com.google.guava:18.0.0.redhat-1]
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2197)[129:com.google.guava:18.0.0.redhat-1]
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3937)[129:com.google.guava:18.0.0.redhat-1]
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3941)[129:com.google.guava:18.0.0.redhat-1]
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4824)[129:com.google.guava:18.0.0.redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.LoadingCacheUtils.getCacheValue(LoadingCacheUtils.java:49)[348:org.jboss.weld.osgi-bundle:2.3.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.weld.util.cache.LoadingCacheUtils.getCastCacheValue(LoadingCacheUtils.java:74)[348:org.jboss.weld.osgi-bundle:2.3.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getBackedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:175)[348:org.jboss.weld.osgi-bundle:2.3.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getBackedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:194)[348:org.jboss.weld.osgi-bundle:2.3.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.AnnotatedTypeLoader.loadAnnotatedType(AnnotatedTypeLoader.java:78)[348:org.jboss.weld.osgi-bundle:2.3.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.AnnotatedTypeLoader.loadAnnotatedType(AnnotatedTypeLoader.java:60)[348:org.jboss.weld.osgi-bundle:2.3.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClass(BeanDeployer.java:97)[348:org.jboss.weld.osgi-bundle:2.3.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$1.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:65)[348:org.jboss.weld.osgi-bundle:2.3.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$1.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:62)[348:org.jboss.weld.osgi-bundle:2.3.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:63)[348:org.jboss.weld.osgi-bundle:2.3.2.Final]
        at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:56)[348:org.jboss.weld.osgi-bundle:2.3.2.Final]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)[:1.8.0_151]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)[:1.8.0_151]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)[:1.8.0_151]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)[:1.8.0_151]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is caused by a version mismatch. From the [OmniFaces homepage](http://omnifaces.org):

> #### Minimum requirements
>
> - OmniFaces 3.x requires Java 1.8, JSF 2.3, EL 3.0, Servlet 3.1, CDI 2.0, WS 1.1
> - OmniFaces 2.x requires Java 1.7, JSF 2.2, EL 2.2, Servlet 3.0, CDI 1.1, WS 1.1
> - OmniFaces 1.x requires Java 1.6, JSF 2.0, EL 2.1, Servlet 2.5

MyFaces 2.2.x is JSF 2.2, not JSF 2.3.

You have 2 options:

1. Upgrade MyFaces to a JSF 2.3 compatible version. This is currently not available yet as final version. Best what you can try is [2.3.0-beta](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.myfaces.core/myfaces-api/2.3.0-beta).
2. Downgrade OmniFaces to a JSF 2.2 compatible version. Currently the latest is [2.6.8](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.omnifaces/omnifaces/2.6.8).

Comment: I have just realized that and come to update the question. You replied before me. Thanks I will try with 2.6.8.

Comment: the version mismatched resolved after downgrading the version as you suggested.

Comment: Thank you very much BalusC!

Comment: to ensure that osgi services loaded before myfaces we added a BeanManagerServlet loadonstartup=1 and then start FacesServlet with 2. Now, omnifaces Beans.getManager(Beans.java:87) throws null pointer. Is there a way to delay it?

Comment: null pointer might be related with pax-cdi, since CDI.current() is null in org.omnifaces.util.Beans#getManager. Anyhow, it is not related with Omnifaces anymore. Thanks again.

Comment: **Edit:** Should I make another question rather than comments? I have a similar issue, I use Mojarra JSF 2.3.3 (stable) Primefaces 6.2 and Ominifaces 3.0 but NetBeans is not able to find the namespace of it. The `omnifaces-3.0.jar` is added just as `Primfaces-6.2.jar is: `~/personal_domain/lib/` (Payara 4.1)  and I use NetBeans and added it as a library like I did with Primefaces 6.2. I also tried moving it to `./WEB-INF/lib/` (which I then had to create) but still NB doesn't consider it.